# ASP.NET RegisterStartupScript() method... vs Response.Write()

Tags: asp.net, callback

Why can't we write a JavaScript code using Response.Write(".....") to serve the same purpose as RegisterStartupScript()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RegisterStartupScript() will correctly wireup you script when it will be loaded from UpdatePanel. By default, code in UpdatePanel update is not treated as script - this should be done manually or by using RegisterStartupScript().

Comment: But what will happen if I use ICallback... -like interfaces to achieve the same goal as UpdatePanel?

What would be the role of RegisterStartupScript() then?

Comment: Looks like it will be same as Response.Write("...") then. I've disassembled this method in Resharper and seems like it does nothing but registers script for UpdatePanel and generates correct <script> tags. If you will not use UpdatePanel you'll not get any actual benefit.

Answer (score 1):

RegisterStartupScript() will place the HTML in the correct place in your HTML (usually at the end, before the `</body>` tag.